# Cannot compile using any external libraries (Codeblocks)

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I cannot compile any code using external libraries on Code::Blocks.

I tried using the boost lambda example:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

I have a global environment variable set up for the library:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwe0x.jpg
...and I think I set up the build options right.
https://imgur.com/a/BP0Xk

But my build can't detect the header file:

```
||=== Build: Debug in boost test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Documents and Settings\Charlotte\My Documents\wxTest\boost test\boo.cpp|1|fatal error: boost/lambda/lambda.hpp: No such file or directory|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Is the upper/lower case mismatch in 'base' and 'include'/'lib' directories intentional ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. No, but I just fixed that and it didn't work.

Comment: Is this still the same error ? Try using "include" instead of <include> and place it after all the std includes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the boost include path in your first image is cut off. But it looks like

```
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_62\boost
```

Right?

That’s most likely incorrect. If you include the lambda header like you did (which is also the usual way to include a boost Header)

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
```

then there needs to exist a file called

```
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_62\boost\boost\lambda\lambda.hpp
```

That does not fit the normal Boost directory layout. There is one `boost` too many in there. Try setting your your global environment Boost path to:

```
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_62
```

Comment: @VVV The way to say *Thanks* on Stackoverflow is to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)
Not accepting an answer that solves your problem will discourage readers from answering your future questions.